# ¿Cómo puedo especificar el tipo de dato necesario de un parámetro de entrada para que la función actué correctamente?

Tags: javascript, funciones

Estoy empezando a programar en JS y tengo una duda con respecto a cómo puedo verificar el tipo de dato de los argumentos de una función. En Python por ejemplo podemos tener un código como este que nos obliga a pasar como parámetro de entrada un *string*:

```
def saludar(nombre:**str**):
   print(f'!Hola {nombre}!')
```

**¿Existe algo parecido en JavaScript?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En Javascript todavía no existe una sintaxis para tipar variables y parámetros. Digo todavía porque hubo una [propuesta](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-type-annotations) de integrar anotaciones de tipo en el lenguaje.

Para suplir esa carencia se crearon otros lenguajes como [typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/).

Lo que se puede usar son comentarios [JSDoc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html). Este es un ejemplo de la documentación:

```
// Parameters may be declared in a variety of syntactic forms
/**
 * @param {string}  p1 - A string param.
 * @param {string=} p2 - An optional param (Google Closure syntax)
 * @param {string} [p3] - Another optional param (JSDoc syntax).
 * @param {string} [p4="test"] - An optional param with a default value
 * @returns {string} This is the result
 */
function stringsStringStrings(p1, p2, p3, p4) {
  // TODO
}
```